# How do I randomly apply CSS style using plain Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a few list entries that I would like to randomly highlight, 1 item only with different background and text color.

As shown below with "list 2" highlighted.

```
<div id="entries">
    <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
        <li><a href="#1">list 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#2" style="color:#fff; background-color:#000">list 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#3">list 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#4">list 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#5">list 5</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How can I achieve this using vanilla javascript without the use of jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty easy (vanilla JS):

```
// Query entries:
var entries = document.querySelectorAll('#entries ul li a');        

// Clean up entries styles
for(var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++){
      var style = entries[i].style;
      style.backgroundColor = null;
      style.color = null;
    }        

// Pick random index
var randomIdx = Math.floor(Math.random() * entries.length);

// Pick random entry's style
var randomEntryStyle = entries[randomIdx].style;

// Set styles
randomEntryStyle.backgroundColor = '#000';
randomEntryStyle.color = '#fff';
```

[JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/qofizo/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: > "Math.round(Math.random() * (entries.length - 1));" is not a good idea, as it doesn't give you an even distribution. The first and the last item just have a half of the chance, the other items have.

Comment: @syntac Yes, you are right. I didn't think about that. 

This option is better:
`Math.floor(Math.random() * entries.length);`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are going to need all these list elements inside an array to choose from. You can accomplish this by writing:

```
var elements = document.getElementById("entries").getElementsByTagName("li");
```

better however would it be, if you gave them a class name "entry", then you could do:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("entry")
```

which would be even safer, cause you can't get any nested `li`-elements.
Next up, we want to choose one from it randomly. You can write the following:

```
var chosen = elements[Math.floor(Math.random()*elements.length)];
```

And now just apply the css you need:

```
choosen.setAttribute("style", "color:white; background-color: black");
```

Or, to even make it cleaner, create a css class called "chosen", define the css, and apply it to the chosen element.

Greets!

Answer (score 0):

With the following code you can get a random colour for a random element's **`background`** and **`text`**.

```
var
  elements = document.querySelectorAll('#entries ul li a'),
  index = Math.floor(Math.random() * elements.length),
  props = ["color", "backgroundColor"],
  colour = function() {
    return "#" + (Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF << 0).toString(16);
  };

for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) elements[index].style[props[i]] = colour();
```

**Snippet:**

```js
/* ----- JavaScript ----- */
var
  elements = document.querySelectorAll('#entries ul li a'),
  index = Math.floor(Math.random() * elements.length),
  props = ["color", "backgroundColor"],
  colour = function() {
    return "#" + (Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF << 0).toString(16);
  };

for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) elements[index].style[props[i]] = colour();
```

```html
<!----- HTML ----->
<div id="entries">
  <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
    <li><a href="#1">list 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#2">list 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#3">list 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#4">list 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#5">list 5</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```